# Sum of multiples of 3 & 5 using LISP

Tags: common-lisp

```
(defun modsum2 (n)
  (let ((summ 0))
    (if (>= n 3)
        (if (or (zerop (mod n 3)) (zerop (mod n 5)))
           (progn (setq summ (+ n summ))
                  (modsum2 (1- n)))
           (modsum2 (1- n)))
        (print summ))))
```

I am trying to get the sum of multiples  of 3 and 5 below the given number. But the code always returns to 0. What is the problem with it?

Comment: The first thing you would need to do is to indent your code correctly, so that the indentation is based on the structure of the code. Currently your indentation looks random. For example the first IF and the second IF are indented the same? Isn't the second one INSIDE the first one. Once

Comment: Once you got the indentation right, look at the code and think about WHEN the PRINT function gets called. To debug this use `(trace modsum2)` and call your function.

Comment: I have corrected the indenting, thans for the notice.

Comment: You've edited the code and indented it not completely. **How does the print statement need to be indented?** If you write more code, then it would be useful to learn how the editor can indent Lisp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re doing far too much work. Just do inclusion-exclusion:

```
(defun modsum2 (max)
  (let ((a (floor max 3))
        (b (floor max 5))
        (c (floor max 15)))
    (/ (- (+ (* 3 a (1+ a))
             (* 5 b (1+ b)))
          (* 15 c (1+ c)))
       2)))
```

To extend this a bit to more than just 3,5:

```
(defun multsum (k max)
  "The sum of multiples of `k' below `max'"
  (let ((a (floor max k)))
    (* k a (1+ a))))

(defun subsequences-reduce (f items)
  (unless items (return ()))
  (loop for (item . rest) on items
    collect (cons 1 item)
    nconc (loop for (len . val) in (subsequences-reduce f rest)
            collect (cons (1+ len) (funcall f item val)))))

(defun modsum (max &rest nums)
  (loop for (len . lcm) in (subsequences-reduce #'lcm nums)
    sum (* (if (oddp len) 1 -1) (multsum lcm max))))

(defun modsum2 (max) (modsum max 3 5))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun modsum2 (n)
  (let ((summ 0))
    (if (>= n 3)
        (if (or (zerop (mod n 3)) (zerop (mod n 5)))
           (progn (setq summ (+ n summ))
                  (modsum2 (1- n)))
           (modsum2 (1- n)))
        (print summ))))
```

Right, now you got it indented. Let's trace it:

```
* (trace modsum2)
(MODSUM2)
* (modsum2 4)
  0: (MODSUM2 4)
    1: (MODSUM2 3)
      2: (MODSUM2 2)

0       2: MODSUM2 returned 0
    1: MODSUM2 returned 0
  0: MODSUM2 returned 0
0
```

You can see that `0` gets printed when the argument to `n` is `2`. Since the `print` form is also the last form, the function returns its value. `(print 0)` returns `0`. Since the return value is in your function used, it just gets returned from each recursive call.

A typical way to repair it would be to have a local recursive function using `labels` inside the `let`. You then need to call the function. Later you would need to return the `summ`.

Answer (score 1):

```
;; your function has some flaws
(defun modsum2 (n)
  (let ((summ 0)) ;; in every call, `summ` is put to `0`!
    (if (>= n 3)  ;; for n = 2, the alternative `(print summ)` is executed
        (if (or (zerop (mod n 3)) (zerop (mod n 5)))
           (progn (setq summ (+ n summ))
                  (modsum2 (1- n)))
           (modsum2 (1- n)))
        (print summ)))) ;; for n = 2 already this is called
;; since summ is set to `0` for this last modsum2 call, it prints 0

;; tail call recursion with inner function
(defun modsum2 (n)
  (let ((summ 0))
    (labels ((.modsum2 (.n)
               (cond ((zerop .n) summ)
                     ((or (zerop (mod .n 3)) (zerop (mod .n 5)))
                      (setq summ (+ .n summ))
                      (.modsum2 (1- .n)))
                     (t (.modsum2 (1- .n))))))
      (print (.modsum2 n)))))

;; tail call recursion with optional accumulator for the proper start
(defun modsum2 (n &optional (acc 0))
  (cond ((zerop n) acc)
        ((or (zerop (mod n 3))
             (zerop (mod n 5)))
         (modsum2 (1- n) (+ acc n)))
        (t (modsum2 (1- n) acc))))

;; using loop
(defun modsum2 (n)
  (loop for x from 1 to n
        when (or (zerop (mod x 3)) (zerop (mod x 5)))
        sum x into res
        finally (return res)))
;; which is equivalent to (thanks @Rainer Joswig):
(defun modsum2 (n)
  (loop for x from 1 to n
        when (or (zerop (mod x 3)) (zerop (mod x 5)))
        sum x))

;; using reduce or apply
(defun modsum2 (n)
  (reduce #'+ (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x) (or (zerop (mod x 3)) 
                                               (zerop (mod x 5))))
                             (loop for x from 1 to n))))
;; instead of `reduce`, `apply` would work, too.
```

Comment: `sum into res finally ...` is not necessary ... `sum ...` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem last week for project euler. I have noticed the way I wrote it does not included in answers. Dropping it here, it might be useful.

```
;;finds the multiple of 3's and 5's below the number n
;;since "or" turns t, whenever one of its arguments returns t. No need to substract multiple of 15.
(defun modsum2 (n)
    (cond ((< n 3) 0)                      
        (t (do ((i 3 (1+ i))
                (summ 0))
               ((> i n) summ)
             (cond ((or (zerop (mod i 3)) 
                        (zerop (mod i 5)))                
                    (setq summ (+ summ i))))))))
```